# Checking whether a Directory Tree Contains File

Tags: file, emacs, directory, predicate, filetree

Is there a function in Emacs to check whether a given existing file lies somewhere "under" a (root) directory, that is anywhere inside the tree structure of the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`find-name-dired`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-and-Find.html) or `find-dired`.

They use the `using the find utility`.